# Unable to move the file

Tags: php, mkdir

I am creating a directory and then moving a uploaded file into it but it gives me this warning

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(): The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in G:\xampp\htdocs\product_management\admin\process\process_product.php on line 43

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'G:\xampp\tmp\phpE5B0.tmp' to '../product_images/10/thumb' in     G:\xampp\htdocs\product_management\admin\process\process_product.php on line 43
```

my code is

```
if($_FILES['thumb']['name']!=="") {
         echo $path = "../product_images/".$insert_id."/thumb";
         mkdir($path,0777, true);
         move_uploaded_file($_FILES['thumb']['tmp_name'],$path);
     }
     exit;
```

Comment: `The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory` sounds relatively clear.

Comment: I can't, in good conscience, leave my answer.. it's too obvious. Even Google doesn't have a ton of results for the error message because it's clear enough how to fix it https://www.google.com/search?q="Warning%3A+move_uploaded_file()%3A+The+second+argument+to+copy()+function+cannot+be+a+directory"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['thumb']['tmp_name'],
    $path.'/'.basename($_FILES['thumb']['tmp_name']));
```

Try the code above. **You can't move a file to a folder.** You move a file to another file name.

Answer (score 1):

the PHP copy function takes as arguments (fromfile, tofile) so you want to actually specify a whole filename as both arguments and not just a directory.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_copy.asp